# go a little crazy

Tags: meaning, idioms

I saw these sentences but I could not understand what does "go a little crazy" mean!?

"the material can assume a lot of formats. And then you go a little crazy, and so you do various optical components or you do microprism arrays"

Comment: It's like [the song says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZuW6BH_Vak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an informal way to say ***do something unexpected or inexplicable***, from the perception that an insane person would act in irrational ways. It's usually used in a humorous context. So in this case, the author is jokingly implying that you would have to be slightly insane to choose various optical components or microprism arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cliche meaning "do something out of the ordinary" used by people who never do anything out of the ordinary and take offense when others do something out of the ordinary.